# Telling the difference between UserLocation Pin and user added pins

Tags: ios, annotations, mkannotationview, mkpinannotationview

I am trying to solve a problem that I'm not sure how to solve. In my app, when the mapkit launches, I drop a pin at the user's current location. The mapkit delegates to viewForAnnotation which sets the pin's color which works fine.

The issue I'm running into is I cannot tell the annotations apart so I can apply a different color to "user added locations" vs. my "current location" pin. I would like to add a button so they can delete any pins they add but not be able to delete their "current location" pin. I can't seem to figure out how to extract any identifiable pieces of information like title or subtitle of the pin.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here's my code...

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    NSLog(@"OAAssignmentGPSViewController.m : mapView viewForAnnotation");

    if([annotation isKindOfClass: [MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;

    NSLog(@" mapView.userLocation.title = %@", self.mapView.userLocation.title);
    static NSString* annotationIdentifier = @"currentlocation";
    MKPinAnnotationView *myPinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
    if (!myPinView) {
    myPinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil] ;
    myPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    myPinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    myPinView.animatesDrop = YES;

    NSLog(@"mapView.description %@", self.mapView.userLocation.title);
    if( annotation   != self.mapView.userLocation)<<<<<----how do I check for UserLocation
    {
        myPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        myPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView =   [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    }
   }
    return myPinView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating this for other newbies, this was the answer...

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) ....{

   this is the current location pin

}else {

    these are you custom locations pins
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to subclass MKPinAnnotationView and add a simple property to index it. Add your pins to an array as they're created and increment the index number. Then, for your "delete all pins" method, something like this where you check the index property of the pin to make sure it's not the first one:

```
-(IBAction)deleteAllPins
{
   for (id pin in self.pinsArray) {
      if (pin.indexNumber >= 1) { //This is not the first pin...
         // Delete the pin
    }

  }
}
```

That's what I would try, anyway. Sorry I don't have time to test it out myself. Hopefully it will get you started. Good luck.